# How is this PCB controlled

Tags: led, pcb, battery-charging

My kids found this PCB on the street. They told me it had apparently been inside a broken bike light or similar. The battery voltage was down at 0.9V and one of the "wires" (what's the correct word?) that connects the battery to the PCB was loose. So, I fixed that broken solder joint and plugged it into a USB outlet.

[image: PCB-with-battery-and-micro-USB-connector]
[image: PCB-with-components-and-LED]

As soon as I plugged it in, the LED2 started blinking. As I see no way to turn it off, it will do so until the battery is completely empty. LED1 appears to be the charging indicator (red when plugged in).

So, how does this work? As it's got no on/off switch, I first expected there to be something like an LDR that would turn the whole thing on automatically in low lights. Nothing like that either.

Putting it under the microscope revealed:

- U1 is the Li-Ion battery charger, part marking "LTH7", [LTC4054-4.2/LTC4054X-4.2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/405442xf.pdf).
- U2 is ?, part marking "F41F".

Comment: A MOSFET that latches on when powered is supplied to it.

Comment: It looks like there's a connector missing on the LED side of the board.  Bridging the two rectangular pads will pull pin 3 of U2 to ground.

Comment: U2 is probably a small microcontroller, such as a PIC10Fxxx. It would be programmed to accept the logic low signal on U2-3 and cycle through functions like OFF, BLINK, and ON. A PIC10F320/322 has RA1 on pin 3, with Vss (GND) on pin 2, and Vdd on pin 5.

Comment: @vir thanks for the very helpful feedback. I was indeed wondering about the rectangle on the silk screen and the pads. Was quite puzzled as all other components have silkscreen labels.

Comment: @PStechPaul spot on, thanks! I bridged the pads and indeed I see it cycle through a couple of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@vir has sharp eyes. There appears to be an SMT connector or an SMT switch such as [these](https://www.ckswitches.com/media/2779/pts636.pdf) missing from the board (photo from [Digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/c&k/PTS636%2520SK25F%2520SMTR%2520LFS/10071765)):

[image]

The spacing of the outer ends of the pads is about 9mm (scaling from the 2032 battery) so the SMT part would fit, though a narrower part would better avoid shorting on the USB connector pins.

Comment: The solder on the pads looks like the switch may have been broken off, or perhaps was not well soldered.